# How can I draw a straight line through the origin in a simple way in SketchUp?

Tags: sketchup

I am new to SketchUp and I find that the inference system of the SketchUp very powerful. Take the very simple example of drawing a straight line. I suppose that if I launch SketchUp and pick the Simple Template, and start to draw a straight line right away, the starting point of the line is on the face that contains the red and the green axes. Then, the inference system makes it helpful if I want to

- Let the line end at the origin of the coordinate system
- Put the endpoint on any of the axes
- Make the line parallel to any of the axes

However, I haven't found a simple way to plot a straight line that goes through but does not end at the origin of the coordinate system. Is there any simple way that this can be achieved in a few steps? Thank you very much in  advance.

I am using SketchUp Make 2017, non-pro version.

**Edit:** It seems two segments that are colinear and both ends at the coordinate origin is not identified as different objects from "a line that passes the coordinate origin".